# Parse what makes a valid object key?

Tags: parse-platform

Presumably @ symbols aren't allowed? What are the rules?

```
{ code: 105, error: 'invalid field name: image@30x25' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reference I can find in the documentation is

> **iOS/OS X, Android, JavaScript, REST**: Keys must be alphanumeric strings
>
> **.NET, Unity**: Keys must start with a letter, and can contain alphanumeric characters and underscores

Bit of inconsistency in the docs there, but for your purposes the answer is the 2nd one.